# Como reconhecer o botão "voltar" nativo do dispositivo android em um aplicativo.

Tags: android

gostaria de saber como eu faço para detectar em uma aplicação que o usuário clicou no botão "Voltar" nativo do dispositivo. Pois eu preciso realizar uma ação caso isso aconteça.

Answer (score 4):

Através do método:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //aqui você controla o voltar fisico do aparelho
}
```

Comment: Ah ok Leonardo. Muito Obrigado.